# Why is Serializable called an interface?

Tags: java, oop, serialization

Does it really fall under the definition of an interface? Wouldn't it be easier to grasp the purpose of interfaces such as Serializable if they were called for example Markers or Indicators?

Answer (score 2):

It's called an interface because it **is** an interface:

```
public interface Serializable {
}
```

> Wouldn't it be easier to grasp the purpose of interfaces such as Serializable if they were called for example Markers or Indicators?

In fact, this kind of interface — an interface that defines no methods — is frequently called a "marker interface."

Comment: It is called marker interface in litterature yes, but not in code

Comment: @JanneTind: So? When `Serializable` was created, Java didn't even have annotations, much less this "marker" concept you speak of. So they used what they had. Nothing to see here, move on...

Comment: Why just not a reserved word?

Comment: @JanneTind: Why not any of a hundred other design decisions? Gosling and crew were under the same kinds of time pressures and constraints as any other project. Using an interface for this is perfectly reasonable, so they did that, rather than create something else. Think of all the plumbing required for something else: A syntax for defining it; an API for checking its existence on a class; etc. If Java had had annotations at the time, they might have used an annotation instead. But they went with what they had.

Answer (score 0):

`Serializable` is an interface, it has not any method or field inside it -

```
public interface Serializable {

}
```

> Wouldn't it be easier to grasp the purpose of interfaces such as
>   Serializable if they were called for example Markers or Indicators?

This `Serializable` is also called marker interface and It is an indicator to a compiler - what to do with the implementing class.
`Serializable` interface was introduced in `java` to pass a special instruction to `jvm` and before any annotation introduced. Now the similar kind of task may be performed by using annotation (I am not talking about replacing `Serializable` interface here). You can pass some information to compiler what to do with an annotation.